Questions about spelling
I'm playing around with spelling in vim. I've discovered that adding i/=! in add spell file marks lowercase 'i' as misspelling though not apparently documented. Also that the following placed in order in add spell file properly corrects spelling of 'cadiz' - Cadiz/! Cádiz/=.
Now I'd like to get vim to recognize 'i.e.' as acceptable inasmuch it won't mark succeeding word as wrong, red underline. Same with e.g.
Any answer?

/= etc. are documented in :help spell-wordlist-format, line 752 (in my version of Vim). You may want to tweak (or disable) the spellcapcheck option to accept lowercase after "e.g.".

Properly punctuated (with commas, e.g., like this) may have less trouble. I haven’t confirmed that though

Quick google suggests US English style is more prescriptive with commas following i.e. and e.g. Other English usage (e.g. UK) less so.
Default vim spell is ok with 'e.g.' but not 'i.e.' (without commas). Given similar usage is this perhaps an oversight of vim spell devs?


/= etc. are documented in :help spell-wordlist-format, line 752

Nothing there suggests you can combine = ! etc e.g., i/=!

It would be good if you could convert the second part of your solution into answer. Two days after you could even accept it yourself. It make it easy for everyone to browse the actual and future answers :-)

For anyone having the same problem, the default English vim spellfile en.utf-8.spl found here has four relevant entries where /regions=usaucagbnz:
i/13
i.e./245
e/134
e.g./245

Note how i and e cover different regions compared to i.e. and e.g.. I assume this is an oversight in compilation of spellfile.
If you want i marked as 'bad' and i.e. marked 'good' put following in en.utf-8.add:
I
i/!
i.e.

Curiously, the following do not work:
I/=
i/!
i.e.

I
i/=!
i.e.

I'm guessing the default spellfile marks single letters as 'good' for lists (?). Personally, I often miss the shift key when entering personal pronoun 'I' and would rather the lowercase 'i' be flagged as 'bad'.

Vim's spell file for English does in fact not contain "e.g." or "i.e.".
Single letters are included in the spell file, this is why "e.g." isn't marked as an error itself.
You can check by searching the output of the :spelldump command.
Other locales (e.g. German) do contain abbreviations like "cf." (although I've never seen anybody use it in German).
The solution is to add those abbreviations manually as described in :help spell-mkspell.
For a temporary quick fix (until you quit Vim), you can do :spellgood e.g..
A vastly inferior solution would be to disable checking for sentences starting with a capital letter everywhere with :set spellcapcheck=.
Although that will affect every sentence, not just after abbreviations.

My en.utf-8.spl file contains i/13 i.e./245 e/134 e.g./245 for region=usaucagbnz. I now see why e.g. and i.e. were treated differently.  I've created a new spell file from LibreOffice install. Thanks for all your help.

@Tom I use the files Vim's spellfile.vim plugin offers to download as opposed to building them from LibreOffice or anything; i.e. they may differ. Feel free to self-answer your question. A comment gets lost more easily than an answer.

Next on the agenda is to fix problem re. other abbreviations needing a period.
